# Not able to install ios ipa file in iphone6 running on iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios9.1

I want to run my .ipa file on my new iphone6, so I added the udid in the developer account in developer.apple.com under device section. Then I edited the provisioning profile (I use while generating the .ipa by clicking on archive option in xcode) and added the device then downloaded it and double clicked and it was installed in the xcode(because I saw that in xcode->preference) then I opened it in text editor and searched for new udid that I added and it was there. Then I archived the project and generated the .ipa file and try to install it through [diawi.com](http://diawi.com). I am not able to install in the new iphone6 but then I tried installing on the other device(whose udid were previously added) and I was able to install on that.

I am using xcode 7.1 beta, iphone6 is iOS 9.1

I am stuck at it for 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the bitcode NO in build settings ?

Comment: bitcode is set to NO

Comment: try same thing with xcode public version. Dont use xcode beta

Comment: I did, using xcode 7.0.1, but still did not worked

Comment: Is you IPA is not able to install or you are getting "Untrusted Enterprise Developer" error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to your info.plist and add one row for "App Transport Security Settings". Make it a dictionary and then in this dictionary add a Boolean "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set the bool to YES. Clean your project and run. See the image.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and after 2 days I found the solution. You had updated iOS version of iPhone using Wifi due to which it does not allow to install apps. You need to reset it again using itunes.